# What's the fastest way to mine a transaction so I can test contracts quickly?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, testnets, testing

I am developing a solidity automated test framework in nodejs that uses events/logging extensively.  The use of events eliminates (I believe) all the RPC simulators out there.  It's also frustrating to chase down simulator problems, I'd rather use a real server that's modified to go faster.

I've hacked up geth to mine transactions every 4 seconds instead of 15-20 seconds, but it's still too slow.  I'd like to run as fast as the VM can execute code.

I'm going to post my patch to geth to do this, but I and others would really like a better answer to this question.   It really slows down development to have to wait multiple seconds for each transaction to complete.  My test suite of about 60 transactions takes about 4-5 minutes to run, and my test suite keeps getting longer...

Please advise on making this geth mine even faster than the answer I propose, or an alternative suggestion as well.

Answer (score 6):

Patch to geth to make it mine faster.  I would really like help in making this about 2x-4x faster than it is now, but it is 5x faster than stock geth:

[March 9, 2016 EDIT - this new patch now mines every second now.  My unit tests that runs 78 transactions runs in about 160 seconds.  I should put out a Gist for this...]

```
    diff --git a/eth/fetcher/fetcher.go b/eth/fetcher/fetcher.go
index d88d919..f03fd30 100644
--- a/eth/fetcher/fetcher.go
+++ b/eth/fetcher/fetcher.go
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@ import (
 const (
    arriveTimeout = 500 * time.Millisecond // Time allowance before an announced block is explicitlrd
    gatherSlack   = 100 * time.Millisecond // Interval used to collate almost-expired announces witfs
-   fetchTimeout  = 5 * time.Second        // Maximum alloted time to return an explicitly requestebk
+   fetchTimeout  = 1 * time.Second        // Maximum alloted time to return an explicitly requestebk
    maxUncleDist  = 7                      // Maximum allowed backward distance from the chain head
    maxQueueDist  = 32                     // Maximum allowed distance from the chain head to queue
    hashLimit     = 256                    // Maximum number of unique blocks a peer may have annoued
diff --git a/eth/peer.go b/eth/peer.go
index 15ba22f..0201057 100644
--- a/eth/peer.go
+++ b/eth/peer.go
@@ -41,7 +41,7 @@ var (
 const (
    maxKnownTxs      = 32768 // Maximum transactions hashes to keep in the known list (prevent DOS)
    maxKnownBlocks   = 1024  // Maximum block hashes to keep in the known list (prevent DOS)
-   handshakeTimeout = 5 * time.Second
+   handshakeTimeout = 1 * time.Second
 )

 // PeerInfo represents a short summary of the Ethereum sub-protocol metadata known
diff --git a/miner/worker.go b/miner/worker.go
index 754a6fc..2b62b59 100644
--- a/miner/worker.go
+++ b/miner/worker.go
@@ -466,7 +466,7 @@ func (self *worker) commitNewWork() {
            tstamp = parent.Time().Int64() + 1
    }
    // this will ensure we're not going off too far in the future
-   if now := time.Now().Unix(); tstamp > now+4 {
+   if now := time.Now().Unix(); tstamp > now {
            wait := time.Duration(tstamp-now) * time.Second
            glog.V(logger.Info).Infoln("We are too far in the future. Waiting for", wait)
            time.Sleep(wait)
diff --git a/p2p/rlpx.go b/p2p/rlpx.go
index aaa7338..ce82eb7 100644
--- a/p2p/rlpx.go
+++ b/p2p/rlpx.go
@@ -57,7 +57,7 @@ const (

    // total timeout for encryption handshake and protocol
    // handshake in both directions.
-   handshakeTimeout = 5 * time.Second
+   handshakeTimeout = 2 * time.Second

    // This is the timeout for sending the disconnect reason.
    // This is shorter than the usual timeout because we don't want
diff --git a/params/protocol_params.go b/params/protocol_params.go
index dcc17e0..21a49c5 100755
--- a/params/protocol_params.go
+++ b/params/protocol_params.go
@@ -29,10 +29,10 @@ var (
    CallNewAccountGas      = big.NewInt(25000)  // Paid for CALL when the destination address didn'e.
    TxGas                  = big.NewInt(21000)  // Per transaction. NOTE: Not payable on data of cas.
    TxDataZeroGas          = big.NewInt(4)      // Per byte of data attached to a transaction that u.
-   DifficultyBoundDivisor = big.NewInt(2048)   // The bound divisor of the difficulty, used in thep.
+   DifficultyBoundDivisor = big.NewInt(1)      // The bound divisor of the difficulty, used in thep.
    QuadCoeffDiv           = big.NewInt(512)    // Divisor for the quadratic particle of the memoryo.
-   GenesisDifficulty      = big.NewInt(131072) // Difficulty of the Genesis block.
-   DurationLimit          = big.NewInt(13)     // The decision boundary on the blocktime duration e.
+   GenesisDifficulty      = big.NewInt(1)      // Difficulty of the Genesis block.
+   DurationLimit          = big.NewInt(1)      // The decision boundary on the blocktime duration e.
    SstoreSetGas           = big.NewInt(20000)  // Once per SLOAD operation.
    LogDataGas             = big.NewInt(8)      // Per byte in a LOG* operation's data.
    CallStipend            = big.NewInt(2300)   // Free gas given at beginning of call.
@@ -57,7 +57,7 @@ var (
    CreateDataGas        = big.NewInt(200)    //
    Ripemd160Gas         = big.NewInt(600)    //
    Ripemd160WordGas     = big.NewInt(120)    //
-   MinimumDifficulty    = big.NewInt(131072) // The minimum that the difficulty may ever be.
+   MinimumDifficulty    = big.NewInt(1)      // The minimum that the difficulty may ever be.
    CallCreateDepth      = big.NewInt(1024)   // Maximum depth of call/create stack.
    ExpGas               = big.NewInt(10)     // Once per EXP instuction.
    LogGas               = big.NewInt(375)    // Per LOG* operation.
```

Here's my genesis.json.  There's lots of other examples out there:

```
{
    "nonce": "0xdeadbeefdeadbeef",
    "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash":     "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x0",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
    "difficulty": "0x001",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
    "alloc": {
        "0x662eb875377b1288f07baa6139432553b7b8b03e": {
            "balance": "1000000000000000000000"
         }
    }
}
```

~

And finally the all important command line.  Note I've changed the cost of gas to 50 wei instead of 50Gwei.  I probably could have done better to just give a bunch of accounts 10M ether.  Also I need to add reading a script that unlocks all the accounts:

```
#!/bin/bash
bin/geth --datadir /home/Pauls/testing/00 --port 30310 --rpc --rpcport 8110 --networkid 4567890 --dev --lightkdf --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --vmdebug --verbosity 6 --pprof --genesis /home/Pauls/sandboxes/myproj/bin/genesis.json --gpomin "50" --gpomax "50" --pprofport 6110 console 2> /home/Pauls/testing/00/geth.log
```

~

Comment: i've been told that testrpc now supports events.  I'll give it a try when I have some time.

Answer (score 4):

[Test-RPC](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-testrpc) is a great application for doing exactly this. It runs a simulated blockchain, which you can connect to via RPC via web3, and doesn't need to mine or network at all.

Comment: At one point testrpc didn't support events.   It appears to now.   Also, I need a server, not a library, because I'm doing a multi-party application.

However I shall give it a try

Comment: Actually, it is a server. I misspoke

Comment: So how does that compare to https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc

Comment: That one runs on a stripped down NodeJS client, the one I posted runs on a fork of the python client. The JS one looks like it supports events now though, so that may be better.

Comment: I recently tested the nodejs testrpc versus the above geth patch.  Believe or not, geth mines faster with the above patch.  Something happened since the earlier version of ethereumjs/testrpc to slow it down.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use [pyethereum.tester, **pytester**](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/tester.py) for short (and not to be confused with py.test).

**pytester** is part of [pyethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum), the Ethereum Foundation's python client which has undergone a security audit (like Geth) and part of the [Ethereum Bounty Program](http://bounty.ethdev.com).  Agree it's frustrating to chase down simulator problems and I wouldn't classify it as one: it has been very reliable and a bug found using pytester could well be a consensus issue in pyethereum itself and worthy of a bounty.

https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/wiki/Using-pyethereum.tester

As you specifically asked about mining, here's an [example of mining 105 blocks `s.mine(105)`:](https://github.com/AugurProject/augur-core/blob/b19dfc5e38383a64eb5a6c23d16342a679547106/src/python_serpent_test.py#L623-L649)

```
from ethereum import tester as t
def test_make_reports():
    global initial_gas
    initial_gas = 0
    t.gas_limit = 100000000
    s = t.state()
    c = s.abi_contract('functions/output.se')
    gas_use(s)
    c.initiateOwner(1010101)
    c.reputationFaucet(1010101)
    assert(c.submitReportHash(1010101, 3232, -1, 222, 0)==-2), "Nonexistant event check broken"
    event1 = c.createEvent(1010101, "new event", 5, 1, 2, 2)
    bin_market = c.createMarket(1010101, "new market", 2**58, 100*2**64, 184467440737095516, [event1], 1)
    s.mine(105)
    gas_use(s)
    c.incrementPeriod(1010101)
    report_hash = c.makeHash(0, 2**64, event1)
    gas_use(s)
    print c.submitReportHash(1010101, report_hash, 0, event1, 0)
    assert(c.submitReportHash(1010101, report_hash, 0, event1, 0)==1), "Report hash submission failed"
    gas_use(s)
    s.mine(55)
    gas_use(s)
    assert(c.submitReport(1010101, 0, 0, 0, 2**64, event1, 2**64)==1), "Report submission failed"
    gas_use(s)
    print c.getUncaughtOutcome(event1)
    gas_use(s)
    print "Test make reports OK"
```

**pytester also works with Solidity code.**  The Ethereum Alarm Clock uses pytester to [mine many blocks](https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-alarm-clock/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wait_for_block) so that it can test, for example, that the clock wakes up far in the future.  The `wait_for_block` is via [Populus](https://github.com/pipermerriam/populus/blob/master/populus/ethtester_client.py), a [framework](http://populus.readthedocs.org/) which uses pytester; Populus also has an option of testing using an actual Geth node.

[Another Solidity example](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/ether_ad/test.py) that suggests the power of pytester to test arbitrarily complex scenarios, is with [ether_ad, under Ethereum's dapp-bin](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/tree/master/ether_ad).

Comment: well, I'm using nodejs, not python.  Can i just set up pytest to listen on a  socket like geth, but mine as fast as possible, without having to write any (or at least very little) python code?

Comment: I'm not sure if pytester can be used like that: would be great if it could and for now may be best to ask on https://gitter.im/ethereum/pyethereum (probably faster response that way)