# Can I run Geth without syncing?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I want to test some api calls using `web3.js` and so I am using `geth` as `HttpProvider`. Can I start `geth` without the syncing?

Is something like `geth --nosync --rpc` available?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`geth --maxpeers 0` will not sync.  `geth --maxpeers 0 console` may be more helpful and will bring you the console: you don't even need the RPC, and can paste in and execute Javascript.

Comment: there are other command line options to tweak, you also may want to speed up mining to make your testing faster.   See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/whats-the-fastest-way-to-mine-a-transaction-so-i-can-test-contracts-quickly

Comment: I'm really close to having a Docker image for the purposes of using geth for  API and solidity testing.   Will let you know

Comment: @eth When I try this I can't send eth. I have empty chaindata and it looks like the block gas limit [is stale](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/72651/cant-send-when-geth-started-with-no-peers). How can I send eth without syncing?