# How does mining work in ethereum private test net?

Tags: contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm working on smart contracts and using Ethereum wallet. I have formed a private test net and successfully deployed smart contracts on that network. But, I didn't get how the miner functionality works in this scenario.

**Why mining is needed in private network?**

Can someone explain me how mining is done in private test net on Ethereum?

Comment: Do you mean why the mining process is mandatory even if you are on a private network?

Comment: What is your main concern? How to mine a transaction in private test net? or How do miners work?

Comment: @FrenchieiSverige Yes. Why mining is needed in private network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you are the only one on this network, and that you are of course a trusty node, mining is important for 2 things: **confirming your transactions** and **creating new coins**.

The transactions are included into blocks that are mined, and since you are the only one on your private network, you also got the reward that you successfully mined the block. An interesting thing you may have noticed is that Ethereum creates a new block even if there is no new transations. From this [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/why-does-ethereum-creates-a-new-block-without-even-a-single-transaction), you can see the answer:

> Those empty blocks are constantly adding new layers of difficulty to
>   ensure the practical immutability of past blocks.

Moreover, you can find more information [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/in-a-private-blockchain-why-do-miners-keep-adding-empty-blocks-to-the-blockchai).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the consensus engine your are using. If you are using Ethash (proof-of-work), you would need to mine blocks (with geth, or ethminer).

If you use a [Parity private network](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Private-chains), you have several additional options.

- The original Ethereum [Ethash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) (proof-of-work).
- You could use the [InstantSeal](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Private-development-chain) engine, which basically listens to new transactions and creates a new block as soon as any transaction is pending.
- The [Aura](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Consensus-Engines#aura) Validator Engine which operates on a proof-of-authority network and achieves consensus by referring to a list of *validators* (referred to as authorities, when they are linked to physical entities).
- The [Tendermint](https://tendermint.com/) engine.

For Geth, there is also a new validator engine in the works, called [Clique (EIP-225)](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225).

*Disclosure, I work for Parity.*