# Unnecessary mining

Tags: private-blockchain

Short Question:

Why is my node mining?

Long Question:

I just deployed Ethereum using the following information:

**Genesis code**

```
{
"config": {  
    "chainId": 7654321, 
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
               },
"difficulty": "0x4000",
"gasLimit": "0x8000000",  
"alloc": {}
}
}
```

**Set up code**
      geth --datadir c:\blockchain init c:\genesis.json

**Node startup**

```
  geth –-identity "blockdb" –-rpc -–rpcport "8258" --rpccorsdomain "*" –-rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" –-datadir "c:\\blockchain" –-port "30303" –-nodiscover –-networkid 7654321 console
```

When I create an account and do Miner.start(), it goes into a long mining cycle

[image]

This goes on and on. Why? The question arises because  I was following this [video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=G3fa7VCVwsc), and his blockchain is not doing anything. Why so?

Is it possible to stop the blockchain from adding unnecessary Blocks? This should save CPU Power right?

Comment: I gave a longer answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/why-does-ethereum-creates-a-new-block-without-even-a-single-transaction/9058#9058

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's **[how blockchains work](https://medium.com/@micheledaliessi/how-does-the-blockchain-work-98c8cd01d2ae)**: they store transactions into blocks and these blocks have to be *mined*.

Your node is basically generating blocks in your private blockchain. These are empty blocks (unless you issue transactions).

In conclusion, your node is doing what it's supposed to do and you can start playing with it.

Comment: I should have specified this then... I was following this video, and his blockchain is not doing anything. Why so?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3fa7VCVwsc

Also, does this mean that Blockchains keep adding blocks forever despite no transactions?

Comment: video starts mining at 11:25, the same thing does not happen

Comment: yes, miners will produce empty blocks even if there are no transactions. But, if there are no transactions, there are few chances that there will be miners to mine in your blockchain. They'd most probably move to a blockchain where they can get some rewards (valuable coins) for wasting resources (blocked hardware and electricity)