# How can I change the gas price or the gas limit when testing with pyethereum?

Tags: gas, testing, python, pyethereum

I've got some code that's ultimately destined to run on a private network. I'm testing it with the lovely pyethereum, doing things like:

```
from ethereum import tester as t

class testMyContract(TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      self.s = t.state()
      code = open('../mycontract.sol').read()
      self.mycontract = self.s.abi_contract(code, language='solidity', sender=t.k0)

   def testExpensiveThing(self):
     mydata = [1000, 3000, 2000, 8000]
     self.mycontract.doExpensiveThing(mydata)
```

This blows up with

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ethereum/tester.py", line 201, in _send
    raise TransactionFailed()
TransactionFailed
```

It doesn't blow up when I pass it less data, and the contract looks quite expensive, so I'm assuming it's breaking because it's running out of gas. Is there a way to pass pyethereum some settings that will allow the transaction to use more gas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `t.gas_limit` and `t.gas_price`.

For gas limit, since you usually only want to set it once:

Set `t.gas_limit` before `t.state()`.  Example `t.gas_limit = 3000000`

Otherwise can do `self.s.abi_contract(code, gas=3000000,...`

(You can set the gas_limit much higher for testing purposes so that you can deploy a very big contract, but best to keep it lower than the real network's block gas limit so that contracts will be deployable on the real network.)

Comment: Thanks, I set t.gas_limit = t.gas_limit * 10 right before calling t.state() and now it's working.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the start gas here:

```
self.mycontract = self.s.abi_contract(code, gas=3000000, language='solidity', sender=t.k0)
```

But I'm not sure if that's the actual problem