# Error : BlockGasLimitReached: <Transaction(45f6)>: 'gaslimit' actual:4712388 target:3141592

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

I am using testrpc & truffle to build a test local blockchain. I am getting below exception while I run 'truffle test'.

I even tried to manually set the gas_limit variable in tester.py to 4712388 but still getting the same error.

Could you please help me to resolve this.

Thanks,

```
BlockGasLimitReached: : 'gaslimit' actual:4712388 target:3141592
ERROR:jsonrpc.manager:API Exception: {'message': ": 'gaslimit' actual:4712388 target:3141592", 'args': (": 'gaslimit' actual:4712388 target:3141592",), 'type': 'BlockGasLimitReached'} 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonrpc/manager.py", line 108, in _get_responses
    result = method(*request.args, **request.kwargs)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/testrpc/server.py", line 33, in inner
    return rpc_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/testrpc/testrpc.py", line 89, in eth_sendTransaction
    return tester_client.send_transaction(**formatted_transaction)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eth_tester_client/client.py", line 251, in send_transaction
    self._send_transaction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eth_tester_client/client.py", line 55, in inner
    return client_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eth_tester_client/utils.py", line 119, in inner
    return fn(*bytes_args, **bytes_kwargs)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eth_tester_client/client.py", line 213, in _send_transaction
    output = self.evm.send(sender=sender, to=to, value=value, evmdata=data)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ethereum/tester.py", line 341, in send
    return self._send(*args, **kwargs)["output"]
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ethereum/tester.py", line 296, in _send
    (success, output) = processblock.apply_transaction(self.block, transaction)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ethereum/processblock.py", line 142, in apply_transaction
    validate_transaction(block, tx)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ethereum/processblock.py", line 112, in validate_transaction
    raise BlockGasLimitReached(rp('gaslimit', block.gas_used + tx.startgas, block.gas_limit))
BlockGasLimitReached: : 'gaslimit' actual:4712388 target:3141592
```

Comment: For updating the gaslimit in tester.py this might help: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/how-can-i-change-the-gas-price-or-the-gas-limit-when-testing-with-pyethereum

Comment: Thanks for your help . I added the below line apply_transaction(block, tx) method in Processor.py, which worked for me.

block.gas_limit = 4712388

Comment: Glad it helped.  I tried to make the answer clear and feel free to edit it or post your own (and then mark one of them as accepted).  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add

`block.gas_limit = 4712388`

below the apply_transaction(block, tx) method line in processblock.py.

Like this:

```
def apply_transaction(block, tx):
    block.gas_limit = 4712388
    validate_transaction(block, tx)
```