# Private chain: Maximum size of "data" field in an Ethereum transaction?

Tags: transactions, gas, private-blockchain, gas-limit, calldata

The **data** field can be used to send arbitrary data in a transaction. I am aware that the amount of gas required increases with the increase in size of data, but, is there a limit to the size that's allowed? According to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size), the transaction size is limited by the block gas limit in Ethereum. But, what if I'm running a private blockchain with no block gas limits (Is this possible?). Does it mean that I can transfer any amount of data between accounts and all of this gets stored in the private blockchain forever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In genesis.json you can set the block gas limit and then see [How can I stop the block gas limit on a private chain dropping to the public chain default?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2892/42)

> Does it mean that I can transfer any amount of data between accounts
>   and all of this gets stored in the private blockchain forever?

Yes.