# What is the max value of gaslimit in genesis.json?

Tags: go-ethereum, gas-limit

What is the max number of gaslimit you can set in genesis.json?

I'd like to put lots of data in one block, so I need to set max gaslimit in genesis.json.

Comment: Hava a look at this [maximum size of data field](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6194/private-chain-maximum-size-of-data-field-in-an-ethereum-transaction) and [transaction size](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size)