# How to issuance/earn/exchange ether coins in private/consortium network?

Tags: ether, private-blockchain

When we building private/consortium blockchain network with Ethereum for cross enterprise business scenario, we need to consider difficulty/gasLimit in initial genesis file to make fast transaction than public ethereum network.

We also know all transactions are NOT free, they need to pay their transations with eth coins. And they can earn eth coins via mining, but not all nodes will become mining nodes, for example, in https://labs.eleks.com/2016/10/secure-document-transfer-built-top-blockchain-technologies.html, how the client nodes can earn eth coins? buy from others? Any suggestion/practice from real project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's your network, you can just premine some coins and distribute them to whoever needs them. It's also a kind of a built-in usage limiter - if you give someone 1 Ether you know they can't bombard the network with ridiculous transactions.

Of course you also need some miner nodes but if you wish, you can just funnel their rewards to your own account to have greated control in how much transactions everyone can send to the network.

Of course you might also not want to limit the transactions in this way and then you could just distribute 'enough' coins for everyone.

Comment: It sounds this solution can work as one workaround solution, just like [How to remove gas system from ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1953/how-to-remove-gas-system-from-ethereum) provided solution. thx!